# How to send multiple values using ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to collect a Facebook user info and then sign them up. How do i include more than one value in ajax?

```
$.signuser = function () {
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        var str = "";
        alert(response.name);
        var fbfname = response.first_name;
        var fblname = response.last_name;
        var fblname = response.id;
        var fblink = response.link;
        var fbusername = response.username;
        var fblink = response.email;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                data: fbfname,
                fblname
            },
            complete: function () {
                //$('#booksloadjif').css('display','none')
            },
            url: "fbpost.php"
        }).done(function (feedback) {
            $('#fg').html(feedback)
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass multiple key / value pairs to PHP as an object in $.ajax

```
$.signuser = function () {
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {

        var data = {     // create object
            fbfname    : response.first_name,
            fblname    : response.last_name,
            fblname    : response.id,
            fblink     : response.link,
            fbusername : response.username,
            fblink     : response.email
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data, // pass as data
            url: "fbpost.php"
        }).done(function (feedback) {
            $('#fg').html(feedback)
        }).always(function() {
            $('#booksloadjif').css('display','none')
        });
    });
}
```

and you'd access them in PHP with

```
$_POST['fbfname'] 
$_POST['fblname']
```

etc, i.e. the keynames in javascript are also the key names for the $_POST array

Comment: ok so how do i access each of them with PHP if they are sent as one thing?

Comment: As @adeneo says, they're all populated into the $_POST superglobal in PHP. Access the data using that. <?php var_dump($_POST) ?> will allow you to see all POST data.